# Flickering preloaded images used for background switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, flicker, preload

I am switching page background every one second. To prevent flickering I preload the images and on start it works, but after few seconds images are again being loaded and that can randomly cause flickering. Chrome Developers Tools are saying that it's being loaded from cache, but at start it doesn't even require loading from cache and it works as it should.

Any ideas? Here is the example:

```
gImages= [
    'assets/img/background/09.jpg',
    'assets/img/background/01.jpg',
    'assets/img/background/08.jpg'
];

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

preload(gImages);

var currentImage = 0;

var SwitchBackground = function() {
    var image = $('#intro');
    image.css("background", 
              "url('assets/img/background/'+gImages[currentImage]"') 
              50% 0 no-repeat fixed');


    currentImage++;

    if(currentImage == gImages.length)
    {
        currentImage = 0;
    }
};

window.setInterval(function() 
{
    SwitchBackground();
}, 1000);
```

Oh one more thing I noticed, first load is always from (Initiator) jquery-1.10.2.js:4112. On Initiator mouse over it says something about bootstraps, which are also used. After that, the initiator is always the same, jquery-1.10.2.js:7031. Any ideas?

Edit: jquery-1.10.2.js:7031 is triggered by switchBackground call from my code.

So yeah, my basic problem is the flickering effect that I wish to get rid off :) Thank you!

Comment: When is this js code ran? is it placed plain in a `<script>` tag inside your header? have you tried running it inside a `window.onload`?

Comment: in $(document).ready(function() scope

Comment: have you tried window.onload instead of document.onready? they are different signals

Comment: It's the same. Maybe I am expecting to much, I'm not sure. I will strip down my page and see if I can do anything about flickering.

Comment: i was thinking about this again today, the point is it won't make your page wait for the images, it will just trigger their loading earlier. if you want it to load completely, you will need to listen on each individual image's onload function and once all of them are loaded, activate your page

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. Currently started working on something else, but will definitely get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(currentImage == gImages.length)
{
     currentImage = 0;
     SwitchBackground();
}
```

Whenever `currentImage` is equal to the image array length, you set the `currentImage` to 0 and force a switch background which conflicts with your `setInterval` and is most likely the cause of your flicker.

Comment: Fixed, but it's still the same :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wait for all the images to load before start showing them

```
var count = 0;
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
   _.each(arrayOfImages, function(imageSource){
          var imageElement = new Image();
          imageElement.onload = function () {
              count++;
              if (count === arrayOfImages.length) {
                  tada();//here you activate your page
              }
          };
          imageElement.src = imageSource;
   });
}
```

Comment: so tada() is my $(document).ready(function() {} ? Got no clue how to use this :)

Comment: tada is where you show the content in your page. what i've written goes *into* your document.onready

Comment: thanks, testing it out: here is the test page .. it's still work in progress http://www.dreamon.si/test/ It works for me, but some are saying it can still randomly flicker

Comment: I think your server is still serving the old version, the one with the simple `for` loop

Comment: There, uploaded the page with your code. My friend is still having problems .. he says loading of images isn't in order but all messed up, as if preloading doesn't work at all :( And loading takes places on defined interval, 10 seconds that is.
Is maybe .prev() call causing the problems? Or maybe parallax?

Comment: The code seems to work fine for me, when it comes to preloading the images. It enters the `if (count === imageArray.length)` at the right time. concerning the screenshot, you need to empty your cache (or disable it for that matter) when testing this kind of operations to get accurate results everytime you test

Comment: Unfortunately I can't figure out what is causing the flickering. All I know is if the network in the chrome Developer tools is not showing load of the next image, flickering does't happen.